# How to separately allow argument/parameter mismatches in Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues, vscode?

Tags: python-3.x, pylance

The Pylance `reportGeneralTypeIssues` does not work for several third-party libraries that I use daily. I disabled it in VSCode settings

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "none",
    },
```

However, I find the detection of argument/parameter mismatches really useful. Is there a way to dedicatedly allow `argument/parameter mismatches`?

You may please use this code to check.

```
def myfunc(a1: str):
    return a1

myfunc(1)  # It should give the error that 1 is int nor str.
myfunc()  # It should give the error that an argument is missing.
```

Thanks.